# Cant get my connection to a MySQL from asp.net mvc project to work

Tags: mysql, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to get MVC 3 Application to use a MySql database, but I keep getting errors, I have made the following connectionstring and provider in my Web.Config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=xxxxx.unoeuro.com; userid=xxxxx_dk;password=xxxxx;pooling=yes;Database=xxxxx_dk_db" providerName="MySql_db"/>
</connectionStrings>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySql_db" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.1.54.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

But when I try to use it (Just trying to use the default register user that is in a default project) I get this error

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   system.data: Column 'InvariantName' is constrained to be unique. 
>   Value 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is already present.

But I if I remove the DbProviderFactories I just get an error that there is missing a data provider, so its not becuase I duplicated it anywhere

Comment: cut the DbProviderFactories section from your web.config and post the error you are getting after this action. This shouldn't be needed.

Comment: If I remove that then I just get "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon @Ladislav Mrnka's answer, the error is probably occurring because the setting in Web.config is conflicting with one in machine.config. To eliminate the error, add a "remove" tag to your Web.config as follows.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
        <add name="MySql_db" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.1.54.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provider name in connection string must be set to invariant name of provider factory. Also the error most probably says that you already have `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` installed on your machine and registered in Machine.config.

Comment: I followed a guide and added my MySql database as a OCDB connection in my Server explorere, now I am just in doubt how my connectionstring should look

Comment: You cannot use ODBC directly because it is not supported by EF.

Comment: Okay then that is another dead end, how do I find the Machine.config? cant find one in my project

Comment: Looks like you are pretty new to .NET, aren't you? Machine.config is top level configuration file with machine scope - it is in .NET installation folder (%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET). This directory will contain x86 and x64 directories with subdirectories per .NET version. Select correct version and open Config directory to find machine.config and top level web.configs per trust level.

Comment: Nah I have made a lot in C# and some in asp.net but I have only used Mssql through TFS and the sql express, never used external databases

Comment: But you obviously don't know basics of your development platform - knowing about existence of Machine.config and why it exists is such basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of MySQL for visual studio and find a compatible version for Connector/NET.

For example, I have used MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7. and Connector/NET 6.7.5, 6.8.3 or 6.9.x. for Visual Studio 2013

uninstall all the other versions of MySQL for visual studio and Connector/NET.

After that Add new item-> ADO.Net Entity Data Model and create the edmx file.
 you can see system.data and system.data.entity in your reference folder of the project.

In your code 
    MyDatabaseEntities myDB = new MyDatabaseEntities();
    use myDB to access your data.

**If you are creating a framework project**, copy everything under  tag from app.config and paste it into your main project's(startup project) web.config file
One thing needs to keep in mind that    this tag should be the first child of  tag.